# Telerik Controls - What is the point of re-registering static scripts in an update panel postback?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, updatepanel

I'm attempting to speed up my website by combining and minifying my [web|script]resource.axd files.

Something based off of and similar to this.
http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid2061F9773188F0AB36F0DC42BC6073E3A935F71F.aspx?s=cdef%3Ajquery (modified to work with ie6)

The telerik controls in my pages render a lot of resouce.axd script tags. They also appear in update panel ajax postbacks in the pipes format.

Left by themselves the script files are run once. However after I combine the files in the regular page post and an update panel update fires. The code gets run a 2nd time due to the script reference in the update panel ajax response.

This results in a bunch of Telerik "`Namespace` is already registered." errors.

(I think this is because it is a seperate script file with a different name however I still get an error when I have the same file name, Telerik.Web.UI.Orientation is already registered)

I've been thinking that I can just remove the script references from the update panel postback altogether as the scripts are already on the page and there should never be any new controls added to the page requiring new scripts.

I've implemented this and I don't see any issues so far. Could there be something forboding that I am forgetting about?

Or is this a valid assumption?

---

Examples:

**Normal Telerik Post**

```
<html>
    ...
    <script src="webresource.axd?d=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf1" />
    <script src="webresource.axd?d=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf2" />
    <script src="scriptresource.axd?d=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf3" />
    <script src="scriptresource.axd?d=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf4" />
    ...
</html>
```

**Normal Telerik UpdatePanel Response**, no issues when requested from non combined page, throws `<namespace>` is already registered error when requested from page with combined scripts.

```
1|...|...|...|
123|scriptBlock|ScriptPath|/ScriptResource.axd?d=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf3|
456|scriptBlock|ScriptPath|/WebResource.axd?d=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf2|
```

**Combined Scripts**

```
<html>
    ...
    <script src="js.axd?path=gdfg78sdfgsd70fghsrg89dg0sdfh0sfh9sfgh" />
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said makes sense and as long as its working I don't foresee any issues.  But I haven't run into this issue myself and I use a lot of telerik controls in update panels.  It does have me a little curious.  I assume you are, but wanted to double check, that you're using the `RadScriptManager`, which will automatically combine those script files for you. And since you mentioned you're aiming to improve performance as much as possible, I'd also suggest looking at their `StyleSheetManager` and `Compression`.

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/compression.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager.aspx

Also, have you considered using their `RadAjaxManager` instead of UpdatePanels?  It should be more lightweight.